# Probability of winning a prize from a doughnut store promotion?

Tags: probability

A doughnut shop is running a promotion, there are 4 possible prizes to be won:
a free coffee, a \$50 gift card, 2 tickets to a baseball game, and $5000 cash.

The odds of winning something is 75%.

The probability of winning coffee is 8 times more than winning a gift card.
The probability of winning baseball tickets is 22 times more likely than winning $5000
There is a 66% chance that you win a coffee.  The probability of winning a giftcard is the same as winning a ticket.

So, what is the probability of winning each prize? I used the following assertions:
$$coffee = 8*giftcard$$
$$tickets = 22*money$$
$$coffee = 0.66$$
$$giftcard = ticket$$

So, based on this it seems logical that the probability is:

$$ticket = giftcard = \frac{0.66}{8}$$
$$money = \frac{ticket}{22}$$

If we add these all up, we get $75\%$ However, apparently this is wrong.  What is the correct answer?

Comment: I will assume that winning something is mutually exclusive with winning another prize, i.e, it is not possible to win two prizes.

Let the giftcard be probability $p$

Probability of coffee is $8p$

We know that probability for basketball ticket is also $p$,

and we know that probability for the cash prize is $\dfrac{p}{22}$

Since these events are mutually exclusive, the total probability is the sum.


$$p+8p+p+\frac{p}{22}=\frac34\\\implies p=\frac{33}{442}$$

**Note**: This is inconsistent with saying probability for coffee is $2/3$.

Comment: Yes.  So wouldn't that solution be wrong since as you said the odds of winning a coffee would not be 2/3 anymore?

Comment: No, it would mean the question has an error. The question is inconsistent with itself.

Comment: So would my solution be wrong as well then?  If we add up all probabilities, we get 75%

Comment: Depends. Your solution is not "right" either, since a wrong question doesn't have a solution. In short, you followed the rules, did what was logical, met a contradiction. You didn't make a mistake. But the question is wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time.